# Оптимизация кода для двух функций

Tags: android, android-button

У меня есть две функции. У них много общих строчек кода, но так же есть и различные строчки. Мне нужно сделать функцию, которая будет содержать общие строчки кода, а в oneFunc() и в twoFunc() указать только отличительные свойства, такие как картинка и т.д. Можно предложить другие варианты оптимизации. Если будут вопросы, обязательно задавайте в комментарии.
Они появляются по этому условию:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Integer value = intent.getIntExtra("value", 0);

    if (value > 0) {
        switch (value){
            case 1:
                oneFunc();
                break;
            case 2:
                twoFunc();
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

oneFunc():

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void oneFunc() {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    final ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParamsDeleteBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 75);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    deleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    deleteButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    deleteButton.setLayoutParams(imageParamsDeleteBtn);
    deleteButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageParamsDeleteBtn.setMargins(50,40,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(deleteButton);

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                if (event.getRawX() + dX != 15) {
                    String s = "Alex";
                } else {
                    Intent int46 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, one.class);
                    startActivity(int46);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX > 100){
                            view.setX(100);
                        }
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX < 15){
                            view.setX(15);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 25);
    editor.apply();

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
        }
    });

}
```

twoFunc():

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void twoFunc() {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    final ImageButton imageView1 = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450,150);

    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
    imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView1.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams1);
    imageView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams1.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView1);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParamsDeleteBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 75);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    deleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    deleteButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    deleteButton.setLayoutParams(imageParamsDeleteBtn);
    deleteButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageParamsDeleteBtn.setMargins(50,40,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(deleteButton);

    imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                if (event.getRawX() + dX != 15) {
                    String s = "Alex";
                } else {
                    Intent int4623 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, two.class);
                    startActivity(int4623);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX > 100){
                            view.setX(100);
                        }
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX < 15){
                            view.setX(15);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 26);
    editor.apply();

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
        }
    });

}
    mainLayout.addView(imageView1);

}
```

Comment: Вынесите отличающиеся параметры как аргументы вашей функции  oneFunc.

Comment: @KosWarm Можете в ответе написать, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю на ваш вопрос. Чтобы не дублировать код на несколько функций выносите отличающиеся параметры как аргументы функций. Например так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Integer value = intent.getIntExtra("value", 0);

    if (value > 0) {
        switch (value){
            case 1:
                oneFunc(this,R.drawable.one,one.class,25);
                break;
            case 2:
                oneFunc(this,R.drawable.two,two.class,26);
                break;
        }
    }

}


@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void oneFunc(final Context context, int imageViewDrawableId, final Class<?> activityClass , int preferenceValue) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    final ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(context); //Передаём контекст из аргументов
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParamsDeleteBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 75);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(context);//Передаём контекст из аргументов
    deleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    deleteButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    deleteButton.setLayoutParams(imageParamsDeleteBtn);
    deleteButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageParamsDeleteBtn.setMargins(50,40,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(deleteButton);

    imageView.setImageResource(imageViewDrawableId);//Берём идентификатор ресурсов
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                if (event.getRawX() + dX != 15) {
                    String s = "Alex";
                } else {
                    Intent int46 = new Intent(context, activityClass); //Здесь также передаём класс открываемой активити
                    startActivity(int46);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX > 100){
                            view.setX(100);
                        }
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX < 15){
                            view.setX(15);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", preferenceValue);//и значение для настроек тоже
    editor.apply();

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
        }
    });

}
```

Также отмечу, что вы везде используете конкретные числовые размеры в пикселях. Что не правильно, так как устройства имеют разное разрешение экрана и значит кнопки у вас получатся разных размеров на различных телефонах. 
Чтобы получить значение в dp используйте ресурсы `dimen` или можете умножить число пикселей на плотность, которая получается так `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`

Comment: В вашем ответе oneFunc() - это общая функция?

Comment: Да. Это видно из switch

Comment: Спасибо огромное!